# Bootstrap4: How do i push the Item C to the bottom in mobile view

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular 5 and bootstrap.

Right now i can do both UI separately by hiding and showing `C` in `desktop` and `mobile` view, But i do want to make sure my codes **are easy to maintain**.

How do i proceed on so that `C` gets pushed down to the bottom when in mobile view?

**Desktop View:**

[image: Desktop view]

**Mobile View:**

[image: mobile View]

Comment: can you add a sample code of the outer HTML model describing the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't happen in normal scenario, you'd have to repeat the contents of column 'C' as it has to do something not normal for Bootstrap grid; for mobile view, we hide the previous 'C' which i named 'C(a)' and show 'C(b)' only for mobile view;

```css
div {
  border: 1px double red
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
      <h3>Column A</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h3>Column B</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block">
          <h3>Column C(a)</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 d-block d-sm-none">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h3>Column C(b)</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I have this as my solution as as well but i am trying not go to this path as it will be difficult to do maintenance in the future.